# How to remove the border in CKEditor shown on mouse scroll

Tags: iframe, ckeditor

I have a funny trouble with CKEditor, it's described as below:

In CKEditor, I create a headline, an iframe or insert an image. It creates a "BORDER" around the content of the headline, iframe or image.

[image: Before scroll]

Now, I scroll the wheel of mouse up or down out of editor area, the "BORDER" still appears as below:
[image: Border still appears when scroll out of editor area]

How I can remove this "BORDER"?

Please help me.

Thank in advance,
Vu

Comment: What is your CKEditor version and environment? Can you paste the source code of your editor content? Can you reproduce this issue on the [CKEditor demo site](http://ckeditor.com/demo)?

Comment: Thank for your replying @AnnaTomanek, I run CKEditor on IE. You access CKEditor demo site, choose Standard editor from menu and then you click on image, some small squares appear around image (conner and beside). I want to remove or hidden or never appear... those squares when I click on image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is IE native feature. Images, floated divs etc. get these resize borders. 
IIRC any element which has [hasLayout](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-haslayout-property/) property will gain these resize handles.

In IE 8-10 there is possibility to block object resizing with - [disableObjectResizing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disableObjectResizing).
Unfortunately IE11 doesn't provide any handles to work around this problem. This is IE11 bug. There is a hack for IE11 which was not included into core code - https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9317#comment:16.

Depending on method used for creating CKEditor, this hack can be for example implemented as follows:
If classic editor and replace method is used -

```
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});  
 editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( evt ){
                editor.on( 'contentDom', function( e ){
                    var editable = editor.editable(),
                        element = editable.$;

                    if ( element.addEventListener ) {
                        // IE up to 10.
                        element.addEventListener( 'mscontrolselect', function( evt ) {
                            evt.preventDefault();
                        } );
                    } else {
                        // IE11 and higher.
                        element.attachEvent( 'oncontrolselect', function( evt ) {
                            evt.returnValue = false;
                        } );
                    }
                });   
            });
```

If classic or inline editors are created automatically -

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( event ) {
    var editor = event.editor;  

     editor.on( 'contentDom', function( e ){
                   var editable = editor.editable(),
                        element = editable.$;

                    if ( element.addEventListener ) {
                        // IE up to 10.
                        element.addEventListener( 'mscontrolselect', function( evt ) {
                            evt.preventDefault();
                        } );
                    } else {
                        // IE11 and higher.
                        element.attachEvent( 'oncontrolselect', function( evt ) {
                            evt.returnValue = false;
                        } );
                    }
         });
});
```

**NOTE:** Please also have a look at https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9317#comment:26. There are other scenarios where resizing might get broken. It would be good to check if this hack works for all of them.

Comment: Thank j.swiderski, I'll try as you suggest!